# python panda find next higher and next lower number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to find the next value in 'y' to my val_test. In this exampel I want
next_up  = 4
next_down = 6
( up and down is in the cooridinat system, not the number value )

```
val_test = 5
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4],
                     'y': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,15,21,8,9]})

df=df.sort_values('y',ascending = True)
next_up = int(df.y.iloc[np.searchsorted(df.y.values,[val_test])])

df=df.sort_values('y', ascending = False)
next_down = int(df.y.iloc[np.searchsorted(df.y.values,[val_test])])

print('next_up = ', next_up)
print('next_down = ',next_down)
```

Comment: If you want to find the closest value, this website could help: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/204549/lookup-closest-value-in-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could stay only within Pandas.
There is no need to sort twice or use Numpy.

```
import pandas as pd

val_test = 5
col = 'y'
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4],
    'y': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,15,21,8,9]})

# default from sort_values is ascending=True
# you create a sorted dataframe in which the index correspond to the ascending order
df_sorted = df.sort_values(col).reset_index(drop=True)  

# you find the id in your sorted dataframe that correspond to your val_test
idx_val_test = df_sorted.loc[df_sorted[col]==val_test].index[0]

# you select the next up value in this sorted dataframe
next_up = df_sorted[col].iloc[idx_val_test+1]
# you select the next down value in this sorted dataframe
next_down = df_sorted[col].iloc[idx_val_test-1]

print('next_up = ', next_up)
print('next_down = ', next_down)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Works exactly the way I want it to. I will try to focus on keeping within the Panda library.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest 2 cases depending on what you need, for example :

- **CASE 1 :** You can validate of real position keeping in mind the boundaries

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4],
                     'y': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,15,21,8,9]})
val_test = 9
for i in range(len(lista)):
    
    if i==0 :
        
        if lista[i]==val_test :
            
            next_up=lista[i+1]
            next_down='Firts number'
             
    
    elif i != 0:
        
        if lista[i]==val_test :
        
            try :
                next_up=lista[i+1]
            except : 
                next_up='Last number'

            try :
                next_down=lista[i-1]
            except : 
                next_down='Firts number'

            break

        
print('next_up = ', next_up)
print('next_down = ',next_down)
```

- **OUTPUT CASE #1**

```
val_test = 9
next_up =  Last number
next_down =  8

# but if you use
val_test = 5
next_up =  6
next_down =  4

Cool !!
```

- **CASE 2 :** You can have problems with the first and last index althougt you can use

```
val_test = 15
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4],
                     'y': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,15,21,8,9]})

next_up = int(df.y.iloc[np.searchsorted(df['y'].values,[val_test])+1])
next_down = int(df.y.iloc[np.searchsorted(df['y'].values,[val_test])-1])

print('next_up = ', next_up)
print('next_down = ',next_down)
```

- **OUTPUT CASE #2**

```
val_test = 15
next_up =  21
next_down =  7
```

But you can have this problem when using val_test=9

```
val_test = 9
next_up =  21
next_down =  7
```